# generate function pointers at compile time

Tags: c++

I have a library taking a callback of type

```
double *(double)
```

Now I want to pass a couple of callbacks which are parameterized on another parameter. More precisely I have a function with signature

```
double f(double, int)
```

Now I would like to write something like

```
for(int parameter: {...some values(known at compile time)...})
{
    //register callback x mapsto f(x,parameter)
}
```

I cannot wrap the callback in a lambda because it would be capturing, so it is not convertible to a function pointer. Also as I understand it, bind objects cannot be converted to function pointers (although I am not really sure why) so I cannot bind the parameter.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

**EDIT**: I would like a solution using the compilers template engine to generate those functions for me.
Also if this is helpfull, I have c++17 and I would also be open to using libraries such as boost hana if necessary.

Comment: How many values (known at compile time) are we talking about? Small enough that it might be reasonable to list each registration instead of having a loop?

Comment: maybe but thats not the point. I would like to know how I can do this without writing the same function or using makros...

Comment: If you make assumptions like that, people may find themselves unable to help you.

Comment: I thought it was clear that I didnt want to just write the same function 20 times. But i edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Interesting. Your clarification mentions wanting to use templates, which is exactly what I had in  mind. Yet you dismissed me because you assumed I was referring to copying a function multiple times or using macros. Like I said, when you make assumptions like that, you drive people away from helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You need some for of storage to keep the bound value, a raw function pointer can't do that unless you create functions using macros at compile time. (or in a far future using reflection+meta classes) Doing this at run time won't work.

What you can use is `std::bind` and then for example store `std::function` instances.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

double function(double, int);

void register_all() {
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    // values to bind
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 4, 6, 8 };
    // our callback registry
    std::vector<std::function<double(double)>> funcs;

    // registration
    for (auto i : v) {
        funcs.emplace_back(std::bind(function, _1, i));
    }

    //call
    for (auto &f : funcs) {
        f(1.0);
    }
}
```

If you can't change the callback type to `std::function` or something similar the only way is to register a single callback doing further calls. i.e.

```
double my_callback(double d) {
  for (int i : whatever) {
    f(d, i);
  }
}

// ... somewhere else
register_callback(my_callback);
```

Side note:
A good C callback API would allow passing a `void*` through, which can be given for extra callback specific information, which could be used to carry the extra data. However the simple function pointer is too limited for anything else.

Edit:

If you know all your (potential) values at compile time you could use a template to wrap:

```
#include <vector>

double f(double d, int i);

template<int i>
double f_wrapper(double d) {
    return f(d, i);
}

int main() {    
    std::vector<double(*)(double)> funcs;

    funcs.push_back(&f_wrapper<0>);
    funcs.push_back(&f_wrapper<1>);
    funcs.push_back(&f_wrapper<2>);

    //call
    double r = .0;
    for (auto &f : funcs) {
        r += f(1.0);
    }
}
```

With some more variadic template magic:

```
#include <vector>

double f(double d, int i);

template<int i>
double f_wrapper(double d) {
    return f(d, i);
}

template<int... id>
void register_cbs(std::vector<double(*)(double)>& funcs) {
    (funcs.push_back(&f_wrapper<id>), ...);
}

int main() {
    // register
    std::vector<double(*)(double)> funcs;
    register_cbs<1,2,5,10>(funcs);

    //call
    double r = .0;
    for (auto &f : funcs) {
        r += f(1.0);
    }
}
```

But again the values have to be known at compile time.

Comment: The question states that `bind` objects cannot be used, with the implication that the interface cannot be changed (which is fairly common when dealing with a library). Seems odd to start answering with an approach that's already been ruled out. Maybe drop the parts of this answer that suggest changing the existing library?